# How to mark non-pure function as pure in Nim

Tags: nim-lang

Is there a way to mark non-pure function `p` as pure? Maybe with some pragma?

I'm using `p` for debug, and it can't be used inside pure `func` procs.

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2MMn)

```
proc p(message: string): void = echo message

func purefn: void =
  p "track"
  
purefn()
```

Error:

```
/usercode/in.nim(3, 6) Error: 'purefn' can have side effects
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for a start you can just use `debugEcho` instead of `echo` - it has no side effects (and it's specifically made for use-cases like that).

In other cases you can "lie" to the compiler by doing:

```
proc p(message: string) = 
  {.cast(noSideEffect).}:
    echo message

func purefn =
  p "track"
  
purefn()
```

as described in https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#pragmas-nosideeffect-pragma, but I would advise against it.

Answer (score 4):

For your case, you can use `debugEcho` inside of echo which fakes having no side effects.

Other than that, you can use the `{.cast(noSideEffect).}` pragma if you're not using `echo` in your real code:

```
proc p(message: string): void = echo message

func purefn: void =
  {.cast(noSideEffect).}:
    p "track"
  
purefn()
```